# Función única para los botones de exportación de todas las Datatables de una web app

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, datatables

En las vistas de una web app con Bootstrap de cualquier versión (clientes, proveedores, tiendas, productos, etc.) se utiliza una Datatable para cada una de esas vistas, en donde se encuentra un listado de los datos de cada tabla con los típicos botones de "*Nuevo*", "*Editar*", "*Borrar*" agregados via PHP y Json. La cuestión es que, además de esto, también incluyo los botones para exportar los datos del Datatable en CSV, Excel y PDF.

Pero como la exportación no me parece convincente, personalizo la exportación de cada botón para cada tipo de archivo a través de [*customize*]. De hecho, el "*customize*" en cada Datatable dentro del apartado "*exportOptions*" para exportar cada tipo de archivo me funciona a la perfección, pero...

No habría una manera de evitar duplicar una y otra vez en cada vista el mismo código y llamar exclusivamente a una función definida por usuario donde se pasan los parámetros necesarios y devolver el documento generado para el usuario?

Por ejemplo, el código (resumido) en cada vista sería:

```
myTable = $('#manageTable').DataTable({
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            customize: function(doc) {
                // Código para personalizar estilos, fuentes, encabezado y pie de página
                ...
                // Fin de código para PDF
            }
        },
        {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            customize: function(xls) {
                // Código para personalizar estilos, fuentes, y títulos
                ...
                // Fin de código para XLS
            }
        }
    } ],
    // Otras opciones de Datatable
    ...
});
```

El código de ambos botones en el [*customize*] son un tanto extensos. Mi cuestión es que en cada vista debe ir el mismísimo código una y otra vez, lo cual me parece engorroso e innecesario.

Lo que me gustaría saber es si es posible hacerlo algo como esto:

```
myTable = $('#manageTable').DataTable({
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            customize: myfunctionPDF(doc, param2, param3);
        },
        {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            customize: myfunctionXLS(xls, param2, param3);
        }
    } ],
    // Otras opciones de Datatable
    ...
});
```

Y luego, viene el archivo js incluido en cada vista, en el que no entiendo qué datos debería retornar para el [*customize*]:

```
function myfunctionPDF(doc, param2, param3) {
    // Código para personalizar documento PDF
    ...
    // IMPORTANTE! Aquí es lo que no sé cómo devolver el documento personalizado
    return ???
}

function myfunctionXLS(xls, param2, param3) {
    // Código para personalizar documento XLS
    ...
    return ???
}
```

Mi duda en sí vendría de qué datos es lo que debo devolver con el [*return*] para que la exportación sea exitosa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

espero que te sirva algo asi, estuve leyendo en la documentacion de Datatables te dejo el link: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/custom

En vez de hacer asi:

```
myTable = $('#manageTable').DataTable({
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            customize: myfunctionPDF(doc, param2, param3);
        },
        {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            customize: myfunctionXLS(xls, param2, param3);
        }
    } ],
    // Otras opciones de Datatable
    ...
});
```

Podes realizar algo asi:

```
myTable = $('#manageTable').DataTable({
 dom: 'Bfrtip',
 buttons: ['getPdf', 'getExcel'],
});
```

y en tu archivo datatable JS donde vos quieras poner funcionalidad algo asi:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.getPdf = {
    extend: 'pdf',
    text: 'PDF', 
    title: 'equipos (se verá equipos.pdf)',
    init: (api, node, config) => {
        $(node).removeClass('btn')
        $(node).removeClass('btn-secondary')
    },//ES PARA SACAR LAS CLASES Q VIENEN POR DEFECTO SI QUERES LO UTILIZAS SINO LO BORRAS.
    className: 'btnDataTable',   //AGREGAS TU CLASE QUE DESARROLLAS LUEGO EN TU CSS
    orientation: 'landscape',   //ORIENTACION
    download: 'open'           //SI DESEAS QUE SE ABRA EN UNA NUEVA VENTANA EL PDF
}
```